# How to delete a certain IE cookie from python?

Tags: python, cookies, internet-explorer

how can I delete IE 8 cookies for a certain site from Python?

Comment: Do you mean from the client or the server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably cleaner and less error prone to use the Python standard library module: [cookielib](http://docs.python.org/library/cookielib.html) this provides functions to manipulate cookies in various ways.

Unfortunately to use this with IE consider the third party extension to this module: [Client Cookie](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/ClientCookie/doc.html). This module contains various "cookie jars" such as `MSIECookieJar` which is what you probably want but also `MozillaCookieJar`. This module does not necessarily work with all version of IE but is worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

I've found out that under Windows seven cookies are stored in

> C:\Users(user)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies

in format (user)@host[\d].txt, so I guess just deleting the corresponding file is way to go.